# How to get images of URL from DB to display in ImageView

Tags: java, android, database, imageview

I'm trying to make a user profile page.

I have done some hard work and managed to retrieve the json objects and store user data in sql database and display these data (string) into TextView such as name and email which works fine.

I also have the URLs to users photos in the same database but I can't retrieve the URL and display on the ImageView just like the other text string..

Could someone kindly show me how to tweak this code to do that?

Please consider this from a Java newbie. Thank you! ^^

```
public class DirectoryDetailMeActivity extends Activity {

String eid; //user ID

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String url_veiw_directory = "http://www.myweb.com/android/include/directory_detail_me.php";

private static final String TAG_ID = "eid";
private static final String TAG_IMG = "photo"; 
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
setContentView(R.layout.directory_detail_me);

new GetDirectoryDetails().execute();

}

class GetDirectoryDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    int success;
        try {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", eid));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_veiw_directory, "GET", params);

            Log.d("my profile", json.toString());

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

            JSONArray directoryObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DIRECTORY); 
            JSONObject directory = directoryObj.getJSONObject(0);

            // It works fine if I give the URL manually. 
            String imageURL = "";

            ImageView imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);    

            ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());        
            imgLoader.DisplayImage(imageURL, imagePhoto);

            TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);                    

            txtName.setText(directory.getString(TAG_NAME));
            txtEmail.setText(directory.getString(TAG_EMAIL));

            }else{

        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be imageURL = directory.getString(TAG_IMG) somewhere? Is it the problem, or is the imageLoader?

Comment: you meant? String imageURL = directory.getString(TAG_IMG);

Comment: When you do String imageURL = directory.getString(TAG_IMG); your string is null? If so, can you try to log your json string?

Comment: @Zoleas, I'm not sure what happen but it displays blank field including the name and email..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fill imageURL with getting url from JSONObject. 
I think JSONObject has image array.

try firstly try this.

```
  String imageURL = directory.getString(TAG_IMG);
  //then
  ImageView imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);    
  ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());        
  imgLoader.DisplayImage(imageURL, imagePhoto);
```

if it doesn't work

```
 JSONArray imageObj = directory.getJSONArray(TAG_IMG); 
 JSONObject img = imageObj.getJSONObject(0);
 String imageURL = img.getString("NewTAG");
  //then
 ImageView imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);    
 ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());        
 imgLoader.DisplayImage(imageURL, imagePhoto);
```

if both of them useless.
In ImageLoder class change this line

```
 InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
```

to this

```
 InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();
```

Comment: @Bans, thank you for helping me on this. unfortunately, the both didn't work. It displays blank content including the name and email filed..

Comment: try debug mode and look at your directory json object. maybe this field empty

Comment: but i think your jsonobject doesn't have url or contains extra uncessary characters.

Comment: do You use https://github.com/thest1/LazyList library? it also needs permission WriteExternalStorage :).

Comment: yes i do have that in Manifest.. thank you for helping me kindly

Comment: ok i remember in ImageLoader class change line 81(maybe diffrent yours) this-> InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(); to this-> InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream();

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure what i need to change. I found a tutorial from here (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

Comment: Find ImageLoader class and change this line.